# PHP, Compile foreach and opline

Tags: php, arrays, compiler-construction, php-internals

I'm trying to figure out how a foreach statement is interpreted by PHP. That led me to use `gdb` while executing a dummy foreach script.

I end up in zend_compile.c, in the `zend_compile_foreach()` function. I see the call to the macro ZEND_FE_FETCH_R that moves the internal pointer of the array/object we loop on.

There are a few things I don't understand :

- How the value is actually returned to the `zend_compile_foreach` context
- Are we nesting calls to `zend_compile_stmt` (and therefore `zend_compile_foreach`) to make the iteration happen ? So is the code compiled N times ? N being the number of elements in the array/object
- What is an opline ?? I see that everywhere I look and I don't know about this

Comment: maybe interesting? [How does 'foreach' actually work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057671/how-does-foreach-actually-work)

Comment: I've found this question/answer, but it's about foreach userland behavior, not internal implementation & execution, but thx

Comment: You're looking at the compiler code. It doesn't loop. The generated virtual machine instructions loop. Try `phpdbg -p* test.php` to see the generated instructions.

Comment: After deeper investigation, I've came to this understanding :
1. opline is an actual instruction that will be executed by the VM. Almost everything before is lexing & compiling into these instruction.
2. zend_compile_foreach() write opline to move the internal seeker forward, write the current value of the var to that opline, execute the loop block of code, and jump back to opnum_fetch, until the fetch emit an exit via fe_fetch_r_exit. So there is no loop, only jump (sort of goto?) to previous opcode to execute code again with a new value. Am I correct ?